# How to present my IPhone screen on Windows

Tags: iphone, windows

I must present my iPhone screen on a skype meeting, but Skype for business does not appear to have that option.

A coworker said me that there is some official app that i could use to share my screen on my desktop computer running Windows 10. Of course, I searched on appstore and the internet with no luck.

So, could you point me out in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use [Mirroring360](http://www.mirroring360.com).
You can mirror from iPads or iPhones to a Windows or Mac computer. Mirroring an iPad / iPhone or Mac screen is achieved using the AirPlay™ technology made by Apple, all you need to do is simply install the Mirroring360 application to the computer you wish to mirror to and start mirroring!

Of course, mirroring a Windows PC screen requires the installation of Mirroring360 Sender on your PC.  Make also sure that the computer and the mirroring device are on the same WiFi network.

You can download from [here](http://www.mirroring360.com/#download-section). You have a 7 days trial, then it will cost 14.99$.

As the website says, this tool is useful for presentations, screening recordings, classrooms and so on.